# How to automate a Chrome extension with UFT

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript, google-chrome-extension, qtp, hp-uft

The new version of UFT 12.01 is supporting up to Chrome 36 when it comes to web content.

What about Chrome´s extensions though?

I read somewhere that they cannot be automated.

From the other hand side, when I use developer tools (12) I can identify buttons, textboxes etc.

Is it possible to test a Chrome extension by using UFT?

PS: I specifically try to automate one extension called POSTMAN - Rest Client (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

Answer (score 5):

UFT's Chrome support doesn't work with other extensions since Chrome [disallows extensions being injected into other extensions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153245#c6).

As a workaround you may be able to use [UFT's Insight option](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2019/04/03/image-based-testing-with-insight/) to automate any technology that UFT doesn't support directly.

Specifically for the **Postman** extension, this is a simple REST Client. I Assume you want to use it in order to test your REST services rather than actually testing the Postman extension. If this is the case wouldn't a more natural way to approach this issue be to use  a UFT API test?
API tests support calling and validating REST services with all the functionality previously available in HP's Service Test.

Comment: Thanks Motti, actually this would have been my alternative.
I was specifically looking into Newman, http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2014/05/12/meet-newman-a-command-line-companion-for-postman/
Would you give me an example of how to use UFT API test with rest services?

Comment: @Pixie, I'm sure UFT's documentation on how to use REST services can help you here. It's pretty simple I think. If you have a WADL you can import that otherwise create the test entities yourself by clicking te "Add REST Service" button in UFT's toolbar.

Comment: OK I´ll have a look. Cheers.